# Folder and File creating with bash scripting

Tags: linux, bash

I have to create 50 folders and each fifth folder should have 2*2 files in it, e.g

```
folder1
.
.
folder5 - has 2 files in it
folder 6
.
.
folder 10 - has 4 files in it 
.
.
folder 15 - has 8 files in it
```

here is my code :

```
#!/bin/bash


n=1 
declare -i countFolder

for (( countFolder = 1; countFolder <= 50; countFolder++ )) 
do 
    mkdir Folder$countFolder
done

for (( countFolder = 5; countFolder <= 50; countFolder = countFolder+5 ))
do

    let "n = n * 2"

    for (( f = 0; f < n; f++ )) do
    cd Folder$countFolder && touch File$f.txt
    done
done
```

Comment: Why is this question marked with python tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with this is that you `cd` into a directory but you never `cd` back.

The simplest way of fixing this is by adding parentheses around the `cd`. These parentheses start a subshell, so the `cd` stays within it:

```
for (( f = 0; f < n; f++ )) do
  ( cd Folder$countFolder && touch File$f.txt ) 
done
```

This is equivalent to but shorter than a manual `cd ..`:

```
for (( f = 0; f < n; f++ )) do
  cd Folder$countFolder && { touch File$f.txt; cd ..; }
done
```

Comment: Or just `touch Folder$countFolder/File$f.txt`

Answer (score 1):

You need to go into the directory, make your files, then leave. The most efficient way to do this is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash


n=1 
declare -i countFolder

for (( countFolder = 1; countFolder <= 50; countFolder++ )) 
do 
    mkdir Folder$countFolder
    ls
done

for (( countFolder = 5; countFolder <= 50; countFolder = countFolder+5 ))
do

    let "n = n * 2"
    cd Folder$countFolder
    for (( f = 0; f < n; f++ )) do
        touch File$f.txt
    done
    cd ..
done
```